# javafx:make stage print another method

Tags: java, javafx, frontend

```
public static int print() {
        int a =1;
        int b =2;
        int c= a+b;
        return c;
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(print());
        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Label l = new Label();

        Pane p = new Pane(l);
        p.getChildren().add(l);
        Scene s = new Scene(p);
        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
```

I want to know how to make the `print()` method be printed on the javafx stage, this is just a easy example, so the situation is that write `3` in label as `new Label("3")` is NOT allowed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setText method of label whne you want to update the value.

So here is what you need to do:

```
l.setText(print());
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: But it's not working. `at application.testOutput.start(testOutput.java:27)` and `Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

Comment: Line 27: `Pane p = new Pane(l);`

Comment: That sounds weird to me.
First you are creating a new Pane (p) with (l).
Then you're getting the children of 'p' and adding 'l' to the children as well.

Umm, does that make sense to you?

Comment: I didn't notice before. Appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

You can just define an integer and then send it to a **String.valueOf()** method.

Or you can just call a print method inside of **String.valueOf(print())**.
These two solutions are the same.

Code down below is an example of potential solution.

```
public class Test extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    int number = print();

    Label l = new Label(String.valueOf(number));       
    StackPane p = new StackPane();

    p.getChildren().add(l);

    Scene scene = new Scene(p, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public int print() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = a + b;
    return c;
  }
}
```